# Pandas DataFrame: Merge rows and keep only unique values from multiple rows as a list

Tags: python

I´m looking to merge rows by some id but the problem is that I want to keep the unique values from multiple rows as a list while only keeping the duplicates from multiple rows as a single element.

The raw data would look like something like this:

```
| id | info1 | info2 | info3| info4|
| -- | ----  | ------| -----| -----|
| 1  | 'a'   |  xxx  |  yyy |      |
| 1  | 'b'   |  xxx  |  yyy |      |
| 2  | 'c'   |  mmm  |  nnn |      |
| 3  |  'd'  |  uuu  |      |      |
| 3  |  'e'  |  uuu  |  ooo |      |
| 4  |  'f'  |  xy   |      |      |
| 4  |  'g'  |  xy   |      |      |
```

(The blanks represent missing values)

The desired output data would look like:

```
| id | info1     | info2 | info3| info4 |
| -- | ----      | ------| -----| ------|
| 1  | ['a','b'] |  xxx  |  yyy |       |
| 2  | 'c'       |  mmm  |  nnn |       |
| 3  | ['d','e'] |  uuu  |  ooo |       |
| 4  | ['f','g'] |  xy   |      |       |
```

I´m quite new to this. Hopefully I expressed myself clear here.

Comment: Outside of `pandas` you could utilize the built-ins `zip` and `set` to work towards a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('id').agg(pd.unique).applymap(lambda x: x[0] if len(x)==1 else x)
```

```
         info1 info2 info3
id                        
1   ['a', 'b']   xxx   yyy
2          'c'   mmm   nnn
3   ['d', 'e']   uuu   ooo
```

**UPDATE**

In case of missing values, we need some little changes and more conditions.

```
(
    df.groupby('id')
    .agg(lambda x: 
         list(set([elem for elem in x if elem==elem]))
        )
    .applymap(lambda x: 
              x[0] if len(x)==1 else list(x) if len(x)>1 else ''
             )
)
```

Output:

```
         info1 info2 info3 info4
id                              
1   ['b', 'a']   xxx   yyy      
2          'c'   mmm   nnn      
3   ['d', 'e']   uuu   ooo      
4   ['g', 'f']    xy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers but I encountered a problem when implementing your code. Basically in my dataset, there are missing values, and your code dropped all columns with missing values, even some columns that don't have any missing values. It seems it only kept columns with no data variation for each id, like 'info2' and 'info3'.

Comment: @YiehYan Could you please update your sample code with missing values that represents your real data? I can't quite follow what your problem is right now.

Comment: I edited it now. I hope it is clear for you now. By the way, I also tried to replace all the missing values by a string, e.g 'na'. Then your code worked. However, still there's a warning message telling me that some columns are not successfully aggregated, and these columns are dropped.

Comment: I updated my answer. It solves your problem, but I think it isn't a good idea to aggregate your data like this (without knowing what you want to do with it) because it makes it harder for future data handling.

Comment: Basically my raw data is very unorganized: for each id there are different features recorded in multiple rows. I have another dataset that specifies all the possible combinations of the features, also recorded in multiple rows, for each combination (new id). I want to identify what combination it is in the raw data for each id. My idea is to include all the features of one combination into one row. Then the new rows can be used as identifiers. I believe there are better ways to do it. I would absolutely appreciate it if you could provide some easier solutions!

Comment: If you are intrigued, you can take a look at my other question post. Basically these two questions compose the main difficult parts of my solution.