# Merge Dataframes based on a column of unsorted/unsortable lists

Tags: python

I want to merge two dataframes based on values from the first dataframe. But the identifier column is filled with lists and to make it worse, the order of the elements within the lists is unsortable and might be different from the order of the elements within the lists from the second dataframe, even though the elements are the same. So basically I want the first dataframe to include more information from the second dataframe based on these unsortable lists.

The first dataframe would look something like this:

```
| id       | Info          |
| -------- | ------------- |
| 1        | ['a','b','c'] |
| 2        | ['a','b']     |
| 3        | ['a','c','b'] |
| 4        | ['c','a']     |
```

And the second dataframe would look like this:

```
| add_info | Info          |
| -------- | ------------- |
| Good     | ['a','b','c'] |
| Ok       | ['a','b']     |
| Fine     | ['a','c']     |
| Bad      | ['b','c']     |
```

Then the desired dataframe would be:

```
| id       | Info          | add_info     |
| -------- | ------------- |------------- |
| 1        | ['a','b','c'] | Good         |
| 2        | ['a','b']     | Ok           |
| 3        | ['a','c','b'] | Good         |
| 4        | ['c','a']     | Fine         |
```

The 'info' column is the only available identifier. In the first dataframe the 'info' column is very badly 'ordered'. I hope I conveyed the idea clearly.
Lastly a side note, the 'lists' can also be arrays. I just wanted to add this just in case it would be easier/harder to solve this problem.

Comment: Are the items in the lists strings? And what does _unsortable_ mean here: _"the order of the elements within the lists is **unsortable**"_?

Comment: Yes they are strings. By unsortable I mean these lists are not numbers and I assume sorting is not possible. But I have not tried to sort them and don't know if sorting these lists in both the dataframes will generate the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider joining them by previously sorting them:

```
df1['Info'] = df1['Info'].map(lambda x: str(sorted(x)) if type(x) == list else x)
df2['Info'] = df2['Info'].map(lambda x: str(sorted(x)) if type(x) == list else x)
```

Afterwards you can safely join them by using:

```
output = df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='Info')
```

Creating your expected output:

```
   id             Info add_info
0   1  ['a', 'b', 'c']     Good
1   2       ['a', 'b']       Ok
2   3  ['a', 'b', 'c']     Good
3   4       ['a', 'c']     Fine
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the comment! It works most of the times. But in my dataset, there are some rows with only one single element instead of a list and they cause problems.  For example, in one row, the cell is one single string value 'abc32' instead of a list of strings as in other rows. After running your code, the value 'abc32' is no longer there and is replaced by ['2' '3' 'a' 'b' 'c']. For single string cells, it always decomposed the string and sorted it first in numerical order and then alphabetic order. Hopefully I explained this clearly and you have a solution to that!

Comment: @YiehYan That's what I said in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349298/pandas-dataframe-merge-rows-and-keep-only-unique-values-from-multiple-rows-as-a/74350135#74350135). It isn't a good idea to store your data with different types (some lists, some strings) because you run into problems like that now. If you remove the part after `applymap` in my answer, you propably won't get an error when running the code of this answer, because every element in `Info` will be a list and be sorted.

Comment: Could you please consider running it with the edit? Regardless, try to provide an example that fully covers the issue you are having. Otherwise, answers will provide incomplete solutions to an incomplete problem.